# CRM 2011 LayoutXml using Fields not Defined in Corresponding FetchXml

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Why can I use fields in LayoutXml that are not in the FetchXml?

I would have thought that to use a field in the LayoutXml it would have to be in the FetchXml, but this works:

```xml
            <layoutxml>
          <grid name="resultset" object="112" jump="title" select="1" icon="1" preview="1">
            <row name="result" id="incidentid">
              <cell name="title" width="150" />
              <cell name="ticketnumber" width="150" />
              <cell name="prioritycode" width="150" />
              <cell name="createdon" width="150" />
              <cell name="plate_businessunit" width="100" />
              <cell name="ownerid" width="100" />
              <cell name="createdby" width="100" />
              <cell name="plate_acknowledgeby" width="100" />
              <cell name="followupby" width="100" />
              <cell name="a_4b5945b8a4a64613afc1ae1d5e6828c7.name" width="100" />
              <cell name="a_4b5945b8a4a64613afc1ae1d5e6828c7.plate_classification" width="150" />
            </row>
          </grid>
        </layoutxml>
        <querytype>0</querytype>
        <fetchxml>
          <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical">
            <entity name="incident">
              <order attribute="title" descending="false" />
              <link-entity alias="a_4b5945b8a4a64613afc1ae1d5e6828c7" name="account" from="accountid" to="customerid" link-type="outer" visible="false">
                <attribute name="name" />
                <attribute name="plate_classification" />
              </link-entity>
            </entity>
          </fetch>
        </fetchxml>
        <LocalizedNames>
          <LocalizedName description="All Cases" languagecode="1033" />
        </LocalizedNames>
      </savedquery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because by specifying the field in the layout XML CRM automatically returns those fields.